# My mic makes white noise

Tags: drivers, sound, audio-recording

My mic is making white buzzing noise in ubuntu this wasn't when I was using Windows with Realtek HD audio drivers, and I think that reason is also drivers, Can anyone tell me how can I get the Enhancement feature that windows drivers gave in ubuntu??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all the mixer settings. The gain may be set too high.

Somewhere in the sound settings or in the panel of your desktop you can change the volume, and there is also a button "audio mixer" or similar that provides more sliders than just the volume. One of them is "microphone gain" (or similar). It really depends on what desktop you are using.

Comment: Thanks that worked I used alsamixer and it did the job